# How to allow anonymous to update a Firestore document but just once?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I try to find the right security rules for my new firestore database.

To simplify, my web application has a list of questions that can be answered by yes or no. The application prompts the anonymous users with a random question, they answer yes or no and it prompts another question.
Later on the users can see the list of questions with the response breakdown (i.e 30% yes, 70% no)

I want to make sure my application won't be abusable by someone malicious, for example by sending 1000 request to answer yes to the same question.

I was watching security rules videos about firestore, but could not find a pattern that would only let legitimate answers go through.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Firestore Security Rules allow you to control access to documents and collections in your database. These rules allows you to create rules that match anything, from all writes to the entire database to operations on a specific document. This also depends on the way you structure your data in Cloud Firestore.

**The Problem:** As mentioned in your question I'm assuming that you need to implement firestore security rules so that an anonymous user can answer any question only once.

So considering your requirement, having collection of Questions and a sub-collection Answers for each question would be the ideal approach for your database. Also another collection to store the browser fingerprint of each user which can be used to show statistics based on the user. The schema for the database would be as shown below.

**Questions collection**

```
Questions
  -question1
    -Answers (subcollection) 
      -answer1
        -answer
        -userId //unique id for each anonymous user
      -answer2
        -answer
        -userId 
  -question2
    -Answers (subcollection) 
      -answer1 
      -answer2
```

Users collection

```
Users
  -user1
    -userId //Unique browser fingerprint or any uniqueId to distinguish anonymou users 
    -answeredQuestions // Array of questionIds of answered questions
```

**Solution:** Now that we know the existing answers for a given question, we can write a security rule for the answers sub-collection restricting the creation of a new answer, if the user has the unique questionId already existing in the array of answeredQuestions in his/her user document in the Users collection .

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Questions/{questionId}/Answers/{answerId} {
      //Only restricting new answers 
      allow create: if  (! questionId in getUserData(request.resource.data.userId).answeredQuestions; 
    }       

    //Function to get the user information
    function getUserData(userId){
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(userId)).data;
    }             
  }
}
```

**Note:** Please make sure that you don't restrict the anonymous user to other questions he has not answered yet.

Hope these pointers help.